# How to add defer to include script

Tags: asynchronous, include, smarty

The software I use for my website uses smarty templates, so each Javascript is added to all pages like this:

```
{script src="/js/jquery.min.js"}
```

Similar lines to this are in the software template files, all of which comprise of .tpl, .js and .css files. These {script} lines are in scripts.tpl, which is called from header.tpl via {include template="scripts/scripts.tpl"}.

I have tried various different ways to add defer or async, but these seem to get stripped out when the code is generated. For instance:

```
{script src="/js/jquery.min.js" defer="async"}
```

When this is parsed, the website source code displays this as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Notice the defer async is completely missing.

Is there a way I can add the 'defer' tag to these {script} includes?

Comment: I've worked very long with smarty, but I haven't encountered `{script...}` yet. What is it? Is it a built-in function, or is it a plugin? Where is it documented?

Comment: Hi. It is in the software template files, all of which are .tpl, .js and .css files. These {script} lines are in scripts.tpl, which is called from header.tpl via {include template="scripts/scripts.tpl"}

Comment: I get that, but what does it do? Where is `{script...}` documented? Afaik it isn't a smarty command, but it might be an extension/plugin I don't know of.

Answer (score 0):

i think you may use literal tags, with in the tag you must call javascript files.

```
{literal} {/literal}
```

Comment: So...

{script src="/js/jquery.min.js" {literal}defer="async"{/literal}}

Won't that cause errors, I didn't think parenthesis could be used inside each other? Maybe I'm wrong. I'll give it a try.

Comment: I tried {literal} tags and it still gets stripped out, don't think I can win this one!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use {literal} tag like this:

```
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
{/literal}
```

And if you want to open curly brace in it, you need to use {ldelim} and {rdelim} instead of curly braces.

http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.ldelim.tpl

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
{script src="/js/jquery.min.js" defer}
```

in place of

```
{script src="/js/jquery.min.js" defer="async"}
```